# Django testing of PDFs - single test passes but same test fails when all tests are run

Tags: python, django, pypdf, reportlab

I have a Django app in which I have been using Reportlab to produce various PDFs. These are all functioning correctly. However, tests are failing in an odd manner.
in various tests I'm using pypdf2.PDFReader like this:

```
    response = self.client.get(pdf_url)
    reader = PdfReader(BytesIO(response.content))
    text = ''
    for page in reader.pages:
        text += page.extract_text()

    self.assertTrue("Apples" in text)
```

I have one test which fails when I run the whole test suite.

```
self.assertTrue("Apples" in text)
AssertionError: False is not true
```

The strange thing is, if I run the single test on it's own, or one single TestCase, everything passes. Also, if I run tests in reverse, I get 2 failures instead of 1.

I checked the content being sent to Reportlab and it contains the string "Apples". PDFReader finds all the other content, but not "Apples".

Comment: Are you sure it is `Apples`, and not some character that looks like an `A` for example (for example ``). OCR software tends to sometimes make mistakes.

Comment: I was just using an example word. There are several paragraphs which should appear in the PDF. I'm testing for certain key words. One of them is not found. I could have made it Bananas etc in the test.

Comment: yes, I get that, but the comment still stands, it is definitely possible that something *looks* like Apples (or Bananas), but is not.

Comment: There an object class in the database and for the test this has been given a name 'Apples'. Hence I'm checking for that in the PDF. But the key thing here is the singular test or all tests in ThisTestCase pass, but the whole suite does not.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf

Comment: The problem with pypdf is I'm using Nix and nix develop gives me 'error: metadata-generation-failed'.

Comment: In any case, pypdf doesn't make any difference, same test fails.